# Does angularjs have feature like changepage in jQuery mobile

Tags: javascript, html, angularjs

Does AngularJs have feature like changepage in jQuery mobile?

> http ://jsfiddle.net/shanabus/YjsPD/

I want to have the same effect in angularjs, but not using jQuery mobile.

Answer (score 0):

AngularJS uses "Routes" to changes between pages. Here is a [tutorial](http://viralpatel.net/blogs/angularjs-routing-and-views-tutorial-with-example/) that explains routes well.

Comment: Yeah, i've already using the "Routes", how to solve the issue that reload every time when change the #action, i just want to have a new page, but not Routes, And my new page need to cover the whole screen, not the part of ng-view